# High chart legend colors in square form

Tags: javascript, typescript, highcharts, angular-highcharts

I need legend colors in square form but its square boxes also appearing on graph which I don't need.

[image]

It is also appearing on the graph which I don't need.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can add the below plugin to use legend symbol drawing method from pie series and set `legend.symbolRadius` to 0.

```
(function(H) {
    H.seriesTypes.line.prototype.drawLegendSymbol = H.seriesTypes.pie.prototype.drawLegendSymbol;
}(Highcharts));

Highcharts.chart('container', {
    legend: {
        symbolRadius: 0
    },
    series: [...]
});
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/0Lf2qupm/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/legend.symbolRadius

**Docs:** https://www.highcharts.com/docs/extending-highcharts/extending-highcharts